# how would I perform a SHA1 hash on a file?

Tags: c#, sha1

If I have a file that I want to monitor for any changes (other than looking at the file date stamps etc).

How could I perform a SHA1 hash on its contents?

**I *think* this is what GIT does, so I just want to learn how to do it**

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just use a FileSystemWatcher?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Because it doesn't work, of course. Only on some supported file systems.

Comment: @Will Even on supported file systems, it is not guaranteed to fire (limited buffer size).

Comment: @vossad01 unfortunate, but true.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\File.ext"))
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        string sendCheckSum = BitConverter.ToString(checksum)
            .Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Calculate the checksum periodically.

Comment: That's a file, he asked about a directory.

Comment: His question says "If I have a file that I want to monitor for any changes" , I read "File" , where do you see Directory?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific application that you described, finding the SHA-1 hash of each file in the directory and then XORing them together would work well.

```
byte[] checksum = new byte[sha1Length];
for each file
   for (int index = 0; index < sha1Length; index++)
       checksum[index] ^= fileChecksum[index]
```

Edited to Add:
As pointed out in the comments, this won't really work. One specific scenerio would be adding two identical files, which would cancel each other out in the XOR.
Perhaps creating a stream with all the file names and timestamps and file hashes and then hashing that would give you what you need.

Edited again:
OK, now you've changed your question! So nevermind!

Comment: xor isn't really advisable if security is a concern (he doesn't say it is, but maybe...).  Instead I'd suggest sorting the files and hashing the hashes.